# Does downloading by clicking on link block javascript?

Tags: javascript, download, anchor

The code for downloading a file or multiple files seems like blocks javascript:

```
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = fileURL;
  anchor.download = filename;

  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.click();
  document.body.removeChild(anchor);
```

After invoking this function my socket connection with server breaks and reconnects in a minute. If I try to use this function for a multi file downloading with a loop, it downloads only the last file in an array and breaks the loop.

I have found a solution by fetching the file and building a blob but it's not the way I wanted to solve this task.

Is there any explanation of why it happens?

Comment: If you do this in a loop, you will eventually break the connection. The browser cannot run more than a few of these. Also never AJAX or download in a loop unless you do await. Even then I recommend you do not download more than one file at a time

Comment: You can probably skip the `.appendChild(...)` and `.removeChild(...)` calls; the download works without them in both Firefox and Chromium. It should save you some DOM recalculations.

Comment: @mplungjan how can I do multiple file download without it?

Comment: You have not provided enough code to help you well. I assume the fileURL is fetched from the server? If you do the click and then use setTimeout to schedule the next instead of using a tight loop it should work better. I would personally prefer receiving a zip file

Comment: Triggering repeated download prompts one after another makes for poor UX anyway. Especially if the browser is configured to prompt for the target location of each download individually.

Answer (score -1):

Download multiple files permission is block by default

> Don't allow sites to automatically download multiple files

You can allow this permission to automatically download multiple files.